# simple if statement to show data or show no data

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

i have an array in a for loop, there is no 'data' and gives me an error message saying cannot find this in 1990. am looking for an if statement where i can use this if there is a row called 'data' if not then leave the chart black and not show any data.

the code is:

```
    Dim array1 As New ArrayList
    Dim array2 As New ArrayList
    Dim array3 As New ArrayList


    For Each row In name1
        array.Add(row("info"))
    Next row



    For Each row In name2
        array1.Add(row("name"))

    Next row

    For Each row In name3
        array2.Add(row("address"))

    Next row


    For Each row In name4
        array3.Add(row("data"))
    Next row
```

my data is showing for the info, name, adderss. data is not showing, it is saying there is no data in the table.
how can i put this into a if statement and then show no data is being presented..

using vb.net

error

```
    If Year1.Contains("data") Then   <------ error on data
        For Each row In name4
            array3.Add(row("data"))
        Next row
    End If
```

error code value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'System.data.Datarow'

Comment: You cannot name a variable with a number as in `For Each row In 1989`, so your code will not compile.

Comment: yeah, changed that to names, do you have any idea about if statement

Comment: If there is no item named `"data"` in the table at all then you don't want a conditional to check for it, you want to just get rid of it.  From the terminology I assume that `row` is a `DataRow` directly pulled from a database?  If there's no column named `"data"` then there's no such column.  The conditional would always evaluate to `false` and would be superfluous.

Comment: @david the data is comming from the database, and sometimes shows it.. thats why i need if statement

Comment: @al123: This would be more clear if you show what the error message is, on what line you receive the error message, what the types of these variables are, and any other relevant runtime information when the error occurs.  From the description you've given it sounds like the error is that there is no such column.

Comment: sometimes in the database there is the row data, and soemtimes not.. i just want a if statement in case..

Comment: @al123: Maybe `If row["data"] Is Not Nothing`?  We can't know for sure without any information about what `row` is, what the database structure is, or what the error is.  You're just asking us to guess.

Comment: Deleted my post below (since it was wrong), and also because not sure what the OP wants.

Comment: just a normal if statement for the array i have made for data, the for each row in name4... to show this, then if statement to show nothing!

Comment: Don’t use `ArrayList`, it’s deprecated. Use a generic container instead.

Comment: @al123: Did my guess work or not?  If not, what is the error?  You're not going to find any help if you refuse to provide any useful information.  We can't debug your code for you.

Comment: at the moment it says there is no data in table name4, but for future i will need the if statement..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the limited information you're providing, I'm making a couple of *assumptions* here:

- `row` is a `DataRow`
- There exists a `DataTable` (which I will call `table`)
- Sometimes there exists a column named `data` and sometimes there does not.  (That is, your schema is not static.)

You can check for the existence of a column on the `DataTable` object in its `Columns` collection.  Something like this:

```
If table.Columns.Contains("data") Then
    ' use the column
End If
```

So your code might look something like this:

```
If table.Columns.Contains("data") Then
    For Each row In name4
        array3.Add(row("data"))
    Next row
End If
```

It's definitely unorthodox to have a non-static database schema.  At the very least that sort of thing should be handled by your database code and not in the application logic.  The `SELECT` query should be returning a static list of columns.

Comment: having an error for ('data') it is saying value of type 'string' cannot be converted to 'System.data.Datarow'

Comment: @al123: On what line?  Show your updated code and indicate where the error is happening.  I can't stress enough that we can't examine code/errors/etc. that you're not showing us.  We're not actually in your computer.

Comment: @al123: Based on that, what on earth is `Year1`?  Is that the `DataTable`?  If so, you need to examine the `Columns` collection on that object, as specified in my answer.

Comment: year 1 is suppose to be the column, but i rote it as name4

Comment: lol, sorry for the confusion david, i see what your talking about.thanks for the help and time.

Comment: quick question while am still trying to figure that error out, what will go in that, as it says the type string cannot be converted...

Comment: @al123: Referring to the code currently posted in your question, it looks like the `Contains` method on whatever `Year1` is accepts an argument of type `DataRow`.  You're passing it a `string`, not a `DataRow`.  This implies that `Year1` itself is *probably* a collection of `DataRow` objects (perhaps a `DataTable`?).  But you're not looking for the existence of a row, you're looking for the existence of a column.  And in the `Columns` collection on the `DataTable` object you can check for one by passing a `string` to the `Contains` method.

Comment: @al123: In order to accomplish what, exactly?  If you're looking for the existence of a column then follow the example in my answer.  Check if the name of the column is in the `Columns` collection on the `DataTable`.  If `Year1` is the `DataTable` then the code might be: `If Year1.Columns.Contains("data")`  Which is exactly what I posted in the answer.

Comment: yeah it is, but its not allowing me to put the "data" in because its a string.

Comment: @al123: Because you're using it wrong.  Note the difference between what you did (`Year1.Contains("data")`) and what I suggested (`Year1.Columns.Contains("data")`).  There is a *very* important difference between those two statements.  Your version is looking for a `DataRow` called `"data"` (which is wrong because `"data"` is a string, not a `DataRow`).  My version is looking for a column called `"data"`.

Comment: got it working now, 
        i had the wrong datatable, i was useding dataset instead. thanks anyway david!